# Passing ID from one view to another and storing it in another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a create page for adding a festival and a page for a user to create an event for that festival. I am trying to pass the festivals id from and store it in my events table. It gets caught on the post back of the create page. Here is the code:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create2(int festID)
    {
        EventsVM events = new EventsVM { festivalID = festID };

        events.eType = db.EType.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.EType);
        events.eType.Add(-1, "----- Add New Event Type -----");

        events.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
        events.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        events.endTime = DateTime.Now;

        return View(events);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create2(EventsVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid != true)
        {
            if (model.selectedEType != -1)
            {
                //db.save stuff from create.
                Events Newevent = new Events();
                Newevent.EndTime = model.endTime;
                Newevent.StartTime = model.startTime;
                Newevent.EventsDate = model.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
                Newevent.EventsName = model.EventsName;
                Newevent.EType = db.EType.Where(p => p.ID == model.selectedEType).Single();
                Newevent.Location = model.Location;
                //Caught here!!!
                Newevent.FestivalID = model.festivalID;

                db.Events.Add(Newevent);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Festival", new { id = model.festivalID });
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Festival");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events");
                //String test = "test3";
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Event Type Picked");
        }

        model.eType = db.EType.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.EType);
        model.eType.Add(-1, "----- Add New Event Type -----");
        model.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        model.endTime = DateTime.Now;

        return View(model);
    }
```

I have to "saved" Festival ID on the details page of the selected festival id

Details.cshtml - Festival

```
 <div>
<h3>Details for Festival: @Model.FestivalName.ToString()</h3>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="table-responsive">
<!--<div class="table">-->
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Festival Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Start Date
            </th>
            <th>
                End Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Town
            </th>
            <th>
                County
            </th>
            <th>
                Festival Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Options
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FestivalName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EndDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FestivalTown.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FestivalCounty.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FType.FType)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    @*                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Options</button>*@
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Festival</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit2", new { id = Model.FestivalId })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
@if (Model.Events != null)
{
    <center><div class="well well-sm" style="width:400px">@Model.FestivalName.ToString() has @Model.Events.Count() Events</div></center>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add Event", "Create2", "Events", new { festID = Model.FestivalId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})
    <br />
    <br />
    <!--<div class="table-responsive">-->
    <div class="table">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Events Name
                </th>
                <th>Events Date
                </th>
                <th>Start Time
                </th>
                <th>End Time
                </th>
                <th>Options
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var e in Model.Events)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => e.EventsName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => e.EventsDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => e.StartTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => e.EndTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Event</li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit2", "Events", new { id = e.ID }, null)</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Events", new { id = e.ID }, null)</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Events", new { id = e.ID }, null)</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>  
}
```

The error I get is when it posts back, the id in the link becomes a 0, so its not saving the id. Any id on how I can fix this?

Comment: Where? I already have it in the link of the post back in the create page?
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Festival", new { id = model.festivalID });

Comment: This is the error I get also : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'festID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create2(Int32)' in 'MyFestival.Controllers.EventsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: that error is because you are passing a null value to the method action, if the value you are pasing is going to be null sometimes you can change your method parameter to Create(int? id) or Create(int id = 0) for optional parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer @Overmachine

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create2(int festID)
    {
        EventsVM events = new EventsVM { festivalID = festID };

        events.eType = db.EType.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.EType);
        events.eType.Add(-1, "----- Add New Event Type -----");

        events.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
        events.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        events.endTime = DateTime.Now;

        return View(events);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create2(EventsVM model, int festID)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid != true)
        {
            if (model.selectedEType != -1)
            {
                //db.save stuff from create.
                Events Newevent = new Events();
                Newevent.EndTime = model.endTime;
                Newevent.StartTime = model.startTime;
                Newevent.EventsDate = model.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
                Newevent.EventsName = model.EventsName;
                Newevent.EType = db.EType.Where(p => p.ID == model.selectedEType).Single();
                Newevent.Location = model.Location;
                //Caught here!!!
                Newevent.FestivalID = model.festivalID = festID;

                db.Events.Add(Newevent);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //Change the model.festivalID to Newevent.FestivalID
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Festival", new { id = Newevent.FestivalID });
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Festival");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events");
                //String test = "test3";
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Event Type Picked");
        }

        model.eType = db.EType.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.EType);
        model.eType.Add(-1, "----- Add New Event Type -----");
        model.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        model.endTime = DateTime.Now;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: what did you change? you just copy my answer

Comment: I added this:

    Newevent.FestivalID = model.festivalID = festID;

Comment: @Overmachine I did add your code at first, but I got a 404, so I just add a bit of code to see would it work and it did, but thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The id is 0 because you are passing the model.ID not the entity id which EF generate after the SaveChanges (propagating changes into database) and add to the ObjectSet. So, the Id will be automatically filled for you. change your code to this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create2(EventsVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid != true)
    {
        if (model.selectedEType != -1)
        {
            //db.save stuff from create.
            Events Newevent = new Events();
            Newevent.EndTime = model.endTime;
            Newevent.StartTime = model.startTime;
            Newevent.EventsDate = model.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
            Newevent.EventsName = model.EventsName;
            Newevent.EType = db.EType.Where(p => p.ID == model.selectedEType).Single();
            Newevent.Location = model.Location;
            //Caught here!!!
            Newevent.FestivalID = model.festivalID;

            db.Events.Add(Newevent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //Change the model.festivalID to Newevent.FestivalID
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Festival", new { id = Newevent.FestivalID });
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Festival");
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events");
            //String test = "test3";
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Event Type Picked");
    }

    model.eType = db.EType.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.EType);
    model.eType.Add(-1, "----- Add New Event Type -----");
    model.eventsDate = DateTime.Now;
    model.startTime = DateTime.Now;
    model.endTime = DateTime.Now;

    return View(model);
}
```